# Python - RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, asyncio

Поздравляю с наступающими праздниками! При попытке более одного раза выполнить `await corountine` выбрасывается исключение `RuntimeError: cannot reuse already awaited coroutine`. Не могу понять причины такого поведения и в чем собственно проблема в нескольких местах получить значение сопрограммы, и какие есть способы решить проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для многократного выполнения `await coroutine` нужно из сопрограммы сделать соответствующую `future`, например через `asyncio.ensure_future`, получать значение так `await future` столько раз сколько нужно и вне зависимости от состояния `future`.